# Can this event handler be simplified and the anonymous function removed?

Tags: event-handling, jquery

Can the event handler in **Fig 1** be simplified by removing the anonymous function? I couldn't find a way to solve this with [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) but perhaps I missed something. The trigger for the custom event is in **Fig 2**.

The use of **.bind** is required, since an older jQuery version is being used and it cannot be updated at this moment.

The signature of **doSomething** expects two arguments, both strings.

**Fig 1: Eventhandler**

```
$(mySelector).bind('EVT_MY_CUSTOM', function (e, foo, bar) {
    doSomething(foo, bar);
});
```

**Fig 2: The trigger**

```
$(mySelector).trigger('EVT_MY_CUSTOM', ['apple', 'banana']);
```

Comment: Where do you see the complexity in these code snippets?

Comment: Why don't you modify `doSomething` so it takes a first argument that it ignores? Then you can bind the event to it directly.

Comment: Is the code working or not.?Anonymous or non-anonymous function does not matter unless you describe your problem clearly?

Comment: @KevinBowersox There is no complexity, but I don't really need the anonymous function...or do I?

Comment: @Barmar What would that look like?

Comment: If you'd pass an object instead of an array to `.trigger`, you could access the data via the `event` object and could simplify the binding to `$(mySelector).bind('EVT_MY_CUSTOM', doSomething);`. But that would only make sense if `doSomething` could work with an object as first parameter. Have a look at the last examples in http://api.jquery.com/trigger/. Since there is no problem with the code, the question is probably a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ though.

Comment: @MESSIAH The code works, but that's beside the point.

Comment: directly bind the function you want to execcute?no nonsense!!!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$('div').bind('EVT_MY_CUSTOM', doSomething)
```

And then in `doSomething`:

```
var fruit = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1); // ['apple', 'banana']
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PKwcC/

If you are already defining `doSomething` elsewhere, create a proxy that strips the event object from the argument list:

```
var proxy = function() {
    doSomething.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
}

$('div').bind('EVT_MY_CUSTOM', proxy)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PKwcC/1/

Comment: What if doSomething is used elsewhere, where only two arguments are passed?

Comment: What if... You should probably post the `doSomething` code in the question if that is a requirement.

Comment: I edited the answer with a proxy solution. But it is unclear if this is what you are asking for :]

Comment: I agree, I have updated my question to clarify that doSomething expects two arguments.